# Use framework in static library

Tags: macos, qt, cmake, frameworks, dynamic-linking

I have a library which is being generated as .a file (to be statically linked). There I want to include Qt framework (QtCore.framework) since I am on OSX. Is that possible? How could I do it using cmake?

My attempt:

In CMakeLists.txt I have

```
FIND_LIBRARY(QTCORE_LIBRARY NAMES QtCore
             HINTS "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/osx/frameworks")
```

Then I print variable ${QTCORE_LIBRARY} and it gives right path.

Then in src/CMakeLists.txt (where my sources are) I link the library
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(libname $${QTCORE_LIBRARY})

However when I launch the compilation it complains because it does not find

> fatal error: 'QtGlobal' file not found

I have checked and QtCore.framework contains QtGlobal header

EDIT: In case someone has same problem I found solution.
I needed to add "${QTCORE_LIBRARY}/Headers" in  my project include directories

Thanks in advance and regards

Comment: `I have seen that target_link_libraries requires an executable` - Wrong. `target_link_libraries` links a library with (another) library as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't using the CMake "config.cmake" provided by Qt5 ?
something like:

```
 # Qt Setting
 set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
 set(CMAKE_AUTOUIC ON)
 set(CMAKE_AUTORCC ON)
 find_package(Qt5  REQUIRED COMPONENTS Core Gui Widgets)
 ...
 target_link_libraries(libname Qt5::Core Qt5::Gui Qt5::Widgets)
```

> CMake can find and use [...] Qt5 libraries. [...] Qt5 libraries are found using “Config-file Packages” shipped with Qt5

src: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-qt.7.html

> In order for find_package to be successful, Qt 5 must be found below the CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH, or the Qt5_DIR must be set in the CMake cache to the location of the Qt5WidgetsConfig.cmake file. The easiest way to use CMake is to set the CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH environment variable to the install prefix of Qt 5.

src: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/cmake-manual.html

Comment: Using this, will cmake be able to find headers?
Now i am seeing fatal error: 'QtSql/qtsqlglobal.h' file not found because qtsqlglobal.h is under Headers, not under QtSql

Comment: No I have downloaded Qt prebuilts and they are stored in custom path. How can I tell cmake how to find them?

Comment: Does your Qt prebuilt directories contain any "*Config.cmake" files ?

Comment: Yes, I am seeing it now Qt5CoreConfig.cmake, but I don't know how to use it

Comment: simply add to `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` the path where this file is located (e.g. `set(CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH "your path to qt" ${CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH})`), then you can use `find_package(Qt5Core CONFIG REQUIRED)`, or passing it in the cli `cmake -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=<qt5corepath> ..`. Beware of the case...